# How to hide a current div and show a new div on clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have links on the left sidebar and corresponding content in the right sidebar, arranged in proper div's.

I want to show one div at a time when you click the links on the left. can anyone help me on this thing?

The HTML is like this :

```
<div id="sidebar2">
       <div id="companyimage"><img src="siteimages/imagetest.jpg"></div>
       <div id="historyimage"><img src="siteimages/imagetest2.jpg"></div>
       <div id="awardsimage"><img src="siteimages/imagetest3.jpg"></div>
       <div id="publications"><img src="siteimages/imagetest4.jpg"></div>
       <div id="portfolio"> Embedded a Issu pdf here . </div>
 </div>
```

The links are present in the sidebar 1.

I used jquery, and was able to hide one and show any other one. But I don't know what to do if one clicks random links. I need to hide the current div and show the corresponding div.

The script i used was :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#showpublications").click(function(){
   $("#companyimage").hide();
   $("#publications").fadeIn(1500);
   });
 });
</script>
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I worked this up for you. It's incredibly basic and will probably need some tweaking, but should get you on your way.

http://jsfiddle.net/bRFgV/

jQuery:

```
 $("#sidebar2 div").hide();

 $("#sidebar1 a").click(function(){
     //First hide all the DIVs
     $("#sidebar2 div").hide();

     //Then show the selected one.
     var divtoshow = $(this).attr("href");
     $(divtoshow).show();
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar1">
<a href="#companyimage">companyimage</a>
<a href="#historyimage">historyimage</a>
<a href="#awardsimage">awardsimage</a>
<a href="#publications">publications</a>
<a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
</div>
<div id="sidebar2">
   <div id="companyimage">companyimage</div>
   <div id="historyimage">historyimage</div>
   <div id="awardsimage">awardsimage</div>
   <div id="publications">publications</div>
   <div id="portfolio"> Embedded a Issu pdf here . </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#sidebar2 > div")` is better for this. With the sample html it does the same, however with a more complex content it won't mess up things.

Comment: Thank's a lot!...i tried typing and hiding each div's, but it was messy if i had to add a new div... this is much slicker.

Comment: My pleasure. The anchor href has to match the ID of the div you want to show, but other than that this should be a simple solution to your problem.